# How do I send a query to a website and parse the results?

Tags: java, web-services

I want to do some development in Java. I'd like to be able to access a website, say for example

www.chipotle.com

On the top right, they have a place where you can enter in your zip code and it will give you all of the nearest locations. The program will just have an empty box for user input for their zip code, and it will query the actual chipotle server to retrieve the nearest locations. How do I do that, and also how is the data I receive stored?

This will probably be a followup question as to what methods I should use to parse the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First you need to know the parameters needed to execute the query and the URL which these parameters should be submitted to (the action attribute of the form). With that, your application will have to do an HTTP request to the URL, with your own parameters (possibly only the zip code). Finally parse the answer.

This can be done with standard Java API classes, but it won't be very robust. A better solution would be [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). Here are some [examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

Answer (score 4):

> This will probably be a followup question as to what methods I should use to parse the data.

It very much depends on what the website actually returns.

- If it returns static HTML, use an regular (strict) or permissive HTML parser should be used.
- If it returns dynamic HTML (i.e. HTML with embedded Javascript) you *may* need to use something that evaluates the Javascript as part of the content extraction process.
- There may also be a web API designed for programs (like yours) to use.  Such an API would typically return the results as XML or JSON so that you don't have to scrape the results out of an HTML document.

---

Before you go any further you should check the Terms of Service for the site.  Do they say anything about what you are proposing to do?

A lot of sites DO NOT WANT people to scrape their content or provide wrappers for their services.  For instance, if they get income from ads shown on their site, what you are proposing to do could result in a diversion of visitors to their site and a resulting loss of potential or actual income.

If you don't respect a website's ToS, you could be on the receiving end of lawyers letters ... or worse.  In addition, they could already be using technical means to make life difficult for people to scrape their service.