# Using Java to pull data from a webpage?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to make my first program in Java. The goal is to write a program that browses to a website and downloads a file for me. However, I don't know how to use Java to interact with the internet. Can anyone tell me what topics to look up/read about or recommend some good resources?

Comment: You could use Apache's [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). Somewhat similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052018/how-do-send-query-to-website-and-parse-results/6052186#6052186)

Answer (score 45):

The simplest solution (without depending on any third-party library or platform) is to create a URL instance pointing to the web page / link you want to download, and read the content using streams.

For example:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    
    
    public class DownloadPage {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            
            // Make a URL to the web page
            URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159118/using-java-to-pull-data-from-a-webpage");
            
            // Get the input stream through URL Connection
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            
            // Once you have the Input Stream, it's just plain old Java IO stuff.
            
            // For this case, since you are interested in getting plain-text web page
            // I'll use a reader and output the text content to System.out.
            
            // For binary content, it's better to directly read the bytes from stream and write
            // to the target file.          
            
            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
                String line = null;
            
                // read each line and write to System.out
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi when I implemnt this, I get the html file in my console. How can I get an specific value from an website

Answer (score 30):

## The Basics

Look at these to build a solution more or less from scratch:

- Start from the basics: [The Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)'s [chapter on Networking](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/), including *[Working With URLs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/index.html)*
- Make things easier for yourself: [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) (including HttpClient)

## The Easily Glued-Up and Stitched-Up Stuff

You always have the option of calling external tools from Java using the `exec()` and similar methods. For instance, you could use [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), or [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/).

## The Hardcore Stuff

Then if you want to go into more fully-fledged stuff, thankfully the need for automated web-testing as given us very practical tools for this. Look at:

- [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) (powerful and simple)
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), [Selenium-RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/)
- [WebDriver/Selenium2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/) (still in the works)
- [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) with [JBehave Web](http://jbehave.org/reference/web/stable/)

Some other libs are purposefully written with web-scraping in mind:

- [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- [Jaunt](http://jaunt-api.com/)

## Some Workarounds

Java is a language, but also a platform, with many other languages running on it. Some of which integrate great syntactic sugar or libraries to easily build scrapers.

Check out:

- [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) (and its [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper))
- or [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) (with great XML support as presented [here](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch10.html) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-scalaxml/))

If you know of a great library for [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/) ([JRuby](http://www.jruby.org/), with an [article on scraping with JRuby and HtmlUnit](http://www.innovationontherun.com/scraping-dynamic-websites-using-jruby-and-htmlunit/)) or [Python](http://www.python.org/) ([Jython](http://www.jython.org/)) or you prefer these languages, then give their JVM ports a chance.

## Some Supplements

Some other similar questions:

- [Scrape data from HTML using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471049/scrape-data-from-html-pages-using-java-output-to-database)
- [Options for HTML Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Comment: There's something I didn't write in that answer: I wouldn't really recommend doing this sort of stuff in Java (you may not have a choice, of course, but I'm just pointing it out). It's doable, and there are loads of tools for that, but Java's inherent verbosity make it not so friendly to experiment with a web service to scrap. Usually, I'd rather do this from a dynamic language with a REPL, or directly from my browser's console, etc... But of course, nothing's stopping you from starting like that and then implementing the solution in Java... or another JVM-based language!

Answer (score 8):

Here's my solution using `URL` and `try with resources` phrase to catch the exceptions.

```
/**
 * Created by mona on 5/27/16.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class ReadFromWeb {
    public static void readFromWeb(String webURL) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(webURL);
        InputStream is =  url.openStream();
        try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MalformedURLException("URL is malformed!!");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IOException();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://madison.craigslist.org/search/sub";
        readFromWeb(url);
    }

}
```

You could additionally save it to file based on your needs or parse it using `XML` or `HTML` libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 11 the most convenient way it to use [`java.net.http.HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) from the standard library.

Example:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
     .version(Version.HTTP_1_1)
     .followRedirects(Redirect.NORMAL)
     .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
     .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("proxy.example.com", 80)))
     .authenticator(Authenticator.getDefault())
     .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
     .uri(URI.create("httpss://foo.com/"))
     .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
     .GET()
     .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println(response.statusCode());

System.out.println(response.body());
```

Comment: I had to add a load of imports: import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpClient.Version;
import java.net.http.HttpClient.Redirect;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;

import java.time.Duration;
and I'm still getting an error with null pointer exception on the authenticator line, not sure what I'm supposed to put in for proxy either :(

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code for my API:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159118/using-java-to-pull-data-from-a-webpage");
        InputStream content = url.openStream();
        int c;
        while ((c = content.read())!=-1) System.out.print((char) c);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can catch the characters and convert them to string.