# Java - Getting page content from URL

Tags: java, url

What am I doing wrong here?
Bear in mind i usually code in C# not java. i now need to convert my c# to java.

Java code :

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
         System.out.println("Hello World");
         boolean output;
         try
         {
            URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159118/using-java-to-pull-data-from-a-webpage");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
            output = true;
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             output = false;
         }
         System.out.println("Result: " + Boolean.toString(output));
     }
}
```

C# code is :

```
using System.Net;


bool output;
try
{
  WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
  string webData = wc.DownloadString("URL");
  output = true;
}
catch
{
  output = false;
}
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + output.ToString());
```

What am I doing wrong in the **Java** Code ?

Errors I receive are:

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
            URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159118/using-java-to-pull-data-from-a-webpage");
            ^
  symbol:   class URL
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
            URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159118/using-java-to-pull-data-from-a-webpage");
                          ^
  symbol:   class URL
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            ^
  symbol:   class URLConnection
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
            ^
  symbol:   class InputStream
  location: class HelloWorld
4 errors
```

when compiling on this site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your C# code is `Using System.Net;` in Java, you **`import`** classes. Here you have not imported [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) or [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) or [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). Basically, add to your Java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.InputStream;
```